# Rails not parsing a valid YAML file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, yaml

I'm trying to parse the following YAML with my Rails (3.2.7) application

```
---
main-menu:
  - mitem: Test1
    controller: user
    action: test
  - mitem: Test
    controller: user
    action: test2
    - mitem: Test3
      controller: user
      action: test
```

Unfortunately straight when I load my file

```
    require "yaml"
    @menu = YAML.load_file(file)
```

I get an error

```
Psych::SyntaxError in User#test

Showing /srv/http/fiss/app/views/layouts/application.html.haml where line #12 raised:

(/srv/http/fiss/app/assets/yaml/menu.yaml): did not find expected key while parsing a     block mapping at line 6 column 5
```

I'm new to Rails (and YAML), however I have checked the code with [YAML Lint](http://yamllint.com/) and apparently the YAML code is valid. What's causes this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
main-menu:
  - mitem: Test1
    controller: user
    action: test
  - mitem: Test
    controller: user
    action: test2
    children:
      - mitem: Test3
        controller: user
        action: test
```

Comment: Thanks that solved the issue.. Rather peculiar tho; I have also tested it with python and likewise Ruby my original version doesn't work. Is this just because of YAML syntax?

Answer (score 27):

The first best thing to do is run your yaml file through http://yamllint.com/

Comment: I second the above. Online YAML Parser found an error a few lines down from where I was getting the "did not find expected key while parsing a block..." error.

Answer (score 2):

You have an indent issue. Do you mean

```
main-menu:
  - mitem: Test1
    controller: user
    action: test
  - mitem: Test
    controller: user
    action: test2
  - mitem: Test3
    controller: user
    action: test
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't explicit with my question. This indentation is purposeful - I'm trying to allow for a `mitem` to have `sub-mitems` (and so on, recursively)

Comment: the indentation is purposeful? blank spaces are meaningful?

Answer (score 0):

Check in your YAML you must have any extra or less spaces before a key value,this helped me.